# Spectrum of a unilateral weighted shift

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional, separable, complex Hilbert space.

Let $T \in B(H)$ be a unilateral weighted shift. i.e. $T e_n= t_n e_{n+1}$, where $(t_n)_n \in \ell^{\infty}$.

Suppose $\lambda \in \sigma(T)$. Show that $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|= \lambda \} \subset \sigma(T)$.

I showed that if $\lambda=1$, then we have $UTU^{-1}=\lambda T$, where $U$ is a unitary. Not sure if this is related to what we want to show.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Just edited the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4001274/unilateral-weighted-shift-operator-and-existence-of-unitary-operator-spectrum-o/4003254?noredirect=1) answer, for any $\mu=e^{i\theta}$ there is a unitary operator such that $UTU^{-1}=\mu T$.

Applying the spectrum to both sides, $$\sigma(T)=\sigma(UTU^{-1})=\mu\sigma(T)$$ This means that $\sigma(T)$ is rotationally invariant. Hence if $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$ and $|z|=|\lambda|$ then $z=\frac{z}{\lambda}\lambda\in\frac{z}{\lambda}\sigma(T)=\sigma(T)$ as well.

Comment: Why do we have the last equality $\frac{z}{\lambda} \sigma(T)= \sigma(T)$? Thank you!

Comment: @csiqrucalree Let $\mu=z/\lambda$.